# HSQLDB ANY array function not working

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE inlist_test_table (
    id  NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm executing the following query

```
SELECT val
FROM inlist_test_table
WHERE id = ANY(?)
ORDER BY id
```

Using this code

```
try (var connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
     var preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(this.getQuery())) {
  var array = connection.createArrayOf("smallint", new Object[] {3, 5});
  try {
    preparedStatement.setArray(1, array);

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(2);
    try (var resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        values.add(resultSet.getString(1));
      }
    }
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("Value_00003", "Value_00005"), values);
  } finally {
    array.free();
  }
}
```

I expect rows with id 3 and 5 to be returned. Instead I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: invalid ORDER BY expression in statement [SELECT val FROM inlist_test_table WHERE id = ANY(?) ORDER BY id]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.marschall.jdbcinlists.AbstractInListTest.plainJdbc(AbstractInListTest.java:43)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid ORDER BY expression
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferencesInOrderBy(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 59 more
```

I am using HSQLDB 2.4.1. The same code is working for Postgres and H2.

**Edit 1**

```
SELECT val
FROM inlist_test_table
WHERE id IN ( UNNEST(?) )
ORDER BY id
```

Does not work as only the row with id 3 (the first element in the array) is matched and row with id 5 (the second element in the array) is not matched.

**Edit 2**

Changing the column type from `NUMERIC(5)` to `int` makes the `UNNEST` code work even if the array element type is `smallint`.

Comment: I believe that with HSQLDB you need to use `... WHERE id IN ( UNNEST(?) ) ...`

Comment: Gord's comment is correct. Please add an answer. In Standard SQL, ANY(...) is an aggregate and means any of the given boolean values is true.

Comment: @GordThompson `IN ( UNNEST(?) )`  does not seem to work, see my edit

Comment: @fredt that's the semantics I want, rows with id 3 and 5 should be returned but only row with id 3 is returned

Comment: "*invalid ORDER BY expression in statement*" seems to indicate a problem that is unrelated to the IN condition

Comment: cc: @fredt - With `UNNEST` I get the same result (just the first row) when the column is `NUMERIC(5)` and the array is `smallint`. However, I get the expected result when both the column and the array are `int`.

Comment: I'll check the test code later. For now,  `id IN ( UNNEST(ARRAY[3,5]) ) ` returns both rows (the array contains INT's).  Note SMALLINT does not cover the full NUMERIC(5) range.

Comment: @GordThompson I found out that changing the column type to `int` is enough to make the `UNNEST` code work, leaving the array element type at `smallint` still makes the code run. I'm aware `smallint` does not cover the full `NUMERIC(5)` range but it does cover all array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HSQLDB you need to use

```
... WHERE id IN ( UNNEST(?) ) ...
```

As of version 2.4.1 there appears to be an issue when the column is `NUMERIC(5)` and the array is `smallint`. That will likely be fixed in a future release of HSQLDB.